# How to add custom field to laravel passport client model and check it

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel passport `Client` model has this fields on `oauth_clients` table:

```
name
secret
redirect
personal_access_client
password_client
revoked
```

And how I can add my custom filed `request_domain_name` to client credentials for check requesting domain name with this custom field value on every request?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate migration

```
php artisan make:migration alter_oauth_clients_table_request_domain_name --table=oauth_clients
```

and inside your migration define new column

```php
Schema::table('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('request_domain_name');
});
```

After that, you can extend `Client` model and add `request_domain_name` column to `fillable` property, than you'll be able to check it.

```php
class Client extends \Laravel\Passport\Client
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'secret',
        'redirect',
        'personal_access_client',
        'password_client',
        'revoked',
        'request_domain_name',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I can create this migrations but where I must add new field `request_domain_name` for check it in every request to API? User which use my API as client will not append domain name on every request. I must check request domain name getting from global var `$_SERVER` and check with client `request_domain_name` value. Where I can do it? @Tarasovych

Comment: *"where I must add new field"* - what do you mean? You can get domain from `Request` object during each request.

Comment: When you create a new `Client`, just insert `request_domain_name`

Comment: For example client request created in `vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php` then validated with this code `$psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);` using method `validateAuthenticatedRequest()`

Comment: How I can append to validation fields list `request_domain_name` too?

Comment: You have to override `validateAuthenticatedRequest` than

Comment: I can't override it, because it is another composer package method. [https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server) I must do it only overriding laravel-passport package or by creating custom middlewares

Comment: You can make your own class than, extend parent class from other composer package and override that method.

Comment: In the middleware you still able to query Client which belongs to current user and check `request_domain_name`

Comment: In laravel-passport already have middleware `CheckClientCredentials` where will be checked client credentials. There can't be solved this problem?