# How to amend this Laravel AuthController login function to check if active column is 0?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel + VueJS Project using Passport for authentication.

I am wanting to set up email verification, where the user has to click a linked email to him to verify.

This part of the process has been completed.

In my users' table I have an `activation_token` column, which populates with the users' token upon registration, and an `active` column which is 0 by default until the user has been verified.

Upon the user clicking the link in the email, the `activation_token` is set to `''` if valid, and the `active` column set to `1`.

This part of the process as described above works correctly.

However, my problem is that my login function does not check to see if `active` is `0` - as if this is the case, refuse access.

The following login function is from my AuthController.

```php
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
            $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

            try {

                $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [

            'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
            'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,

                    ]
                ]);

                return $response->getBody();

            } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
                if ($e->getCode()  === 400) {
                    return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or password', $e->getCode());
                } else if ($e->getCode()  === 401) {
                    return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }

            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

I have been following a tutorial:
[Laravel Passport Auth](https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-passport-in-laravel-5-6-confirm-account-notifications-part-2-5e221b021f07)
But the login function here is different to mine so I am struggling to incorporate this snippet as suggested:

```php
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
$credentials['active'] = 1;
$credentials['deleted_at'] = null;

  if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
```

How do I edit my function above to check to see if `active` = 0 ?

Comment: Hi, don't need custom code for login if you use passport, use passport functions, it's more safer, easier, flexible with more options, i don't know why you persist using custom by now... you can get any data about user with simple login check like "Auth::user()->id" or custom fields ... better change your code to have less lines and cleanse...

Comment: Thank you for that information - I was following a tutorial or Laravel Passport Authentication originally, that's how I ended up with the custom code above.  Can you provide me with some further information on a different solution?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285892/how-to-add-custom-field-to-laravel-passport-client-model-and-check-it

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that got it working from me - which was from this tutorial:

[API Rest with Laravel 5.6 Passport Authentication — Confirm account + notifications (Part 2)](https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-passport-in-laravel-5-6-confirm-account-notifications-part-2-5e221b021f07)

```php
public function login(Request $request)
   {
       $request->validate([
           'email' => 'required|string|email',
           'password' => 'required|string',
           'remember_me' => 'boolean'
       ]);

       $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
       $credentials['active'] = 1;
       $credentials['deleted_at'] = null;

       if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
           return response()->json([
               'message' => 'Unauthorized'
           ], 401);

       $user = $request->user();

       $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
       $token = $tokenResult->token;

       if ($request->remember_me)
           $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
       $token->save();
       return response()->json([
           'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
           'token_type' => 'Bearer',
           'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
               $tokenResult->token->expires_at
           )->toDateTimeString()
       ]);
   }
```